# How to create a CSS grid with 3 columns and unlimited amount of items?

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I trying to create a CSS grid that will have 3 columns where I can add any number of "content DIVs" with the same height, which will be added in order, like so:

```
[1][2][3]
[4][5][6]
[7][8]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: and you found nothing about this when doing a small search ? SO is not a coding service ... also don't understand why this got upvoted ..

Answer (score 16):

A Grid Layout must have a parent element with the *display* property set to *grid* or *inline-grid*.

Direct child element(s) of the grid container automatically becomes grid items.

try below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Grid Elements</h1>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11):

By using `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)` on grid container you will get layout with 3 columns of equal width, and grid layout will by default make all items in each row equal height.

```js
let n = $('.grid .item').last().text();

$('.grid').click(function() {
  const item = $('<div class="item">')
  const text = (n % 7 != 0 ? '' : ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, corporis.')
  item.text(++n + text)
  $(this).append(item)
})
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, corporis.</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 2px;
    margin: 0 16px 16px 16px;
}

.cell{
    padding: 10px;
    width: 33.333%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```